# What are the miracles associated with Sri Trailanga Swami?

Tags: life, saint

[Trailanga Swami](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailanga) was a famous ascetic who used to live in Benaras.

What were some of the miracles associated with Him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Trailanga Swami displayed various miracles. [Paramahamsa Yogananda](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramahansa_Yogananda) has written about some of Trailanga Swami's miracles in Chapter 31 (An Interview With The Sacred Mother) Page 218-219 in his book "[Autobiography of a Yogi](http://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/Autobiography-of-a-Yogi-by-Paramahansa-Yogananda.pdf)":

> Lahiri Mahasaya had a famous friend, Trailanga Swami, who was reputed
>   to be over three hundred years old. The two yogis often sat together
>   in meditation. Trailanga's renown is so widespread that few Hindus
>   would deny the possibility of truth in any story of his astounding
>   miracles. He was one of the siddhas (perfected beings) who have
>   cemented India against the erosions of time.
>
> On many occasions the swami was seen to drink, with no ill effect, the
>   most deadly poisons. Thousands of people, including a few who are
>   still living, have seen Trailanga floating on the Ganges. For days
>   together he would sit on top of the water or remain hidden for very
>   long periods under the waves. A common sight at Manikarnika Ghat was
>   the swami's motionless body on the blistering stone slabs, wholly
>   exposed to the merciless Indian sun.
>
> By these feats Trailanga sought to teach men that human life need not
>   depend on oxygen or on certain conditions and precautions. Whether the
>   great master was above water or under it, and whether or not his body
>   challenged the fierce solar rays, he proved that he lived by divine
>   consciousness: Death could not touch him.
>
> The yogi was great not only spiritually, but physically. His weight
>   exceeded three hundred pounds: a pound for each year of his life! As
>   he ate very seldom, the mystery is increased. A master, however,
>   easily ignores all usual rules of health when he desires to do so for
>   some special reason, often a subtle one known only to himself.
>
> Great saints who have awakened from the cosmic mayic dream and have
>   realized this world as an idea in the Divine Mind, can do as they wish
>   with the body, knowing it to be only a manipulatable form of condensed
>   or frozen energy. Though physical scientists now understand that
>   matter is nothing but congealed energy, illumined masters have passed
>   victoriously from theory to practice in the field of matter control.
>
> Trailanga always remained completely nude. The harassed police of
>   Banaras came to regard him as a baffling problem child. The natural
>   swami, like the early Adam in the Garden of Eden, was unconscious of
>   his nakedness. The police were quite conscious of it, however, and
>   unceremoniously committed him to jail. General embarrassment ensued:
>   the enormous body of Trailanga was soon seen, in its usual entirety,
>   on the prison roof. His cell, still securely locked, offered no clue
>   to his mode of escape.
>
> The discouraged officers of the law once more performed their duty.
>   This time a guard was posted before the swami's cell. Might again
>   retired before Right: the great master was soon observed in his
>   nonchalant stroll over the roof.
>
> The Goddess of Justice wears a blindfold; in the case of Trailanga the
>   outwitted police decided to follow her example.
>
> The great yogi preserved a habitual silence. In spite of his round
>   face and huge, barrel-like stomach, Trailanga ate only occasionally.
>   After weeks without food, he would break his fast with potfuls of
>   clobbered milk offered to him by devotees. A skeptic once determined
>   to expose Trailanga as a charlatan. A large bucket of calcium-lime
>   mixture, used in whitewashing walls, was placed before the swami.
>
> "Master", the materialist said, in mock reverence, "I have brought you
>   some clobbered milk. Please drink it."
>
> Trailanga unhesitatingly drank, to the last drop, the quarts of
>   burning lime. In a few minutes the evildoer fell to the ground in
>   agony.
>
> "Help, Swami, help!" he cried. "I am on fire! Forgive my wicked test!"
>
> The great yogi broke his habitual silence. "Scoffer," he said, "you
>   did not realize when you offered me poison that my life is one with
>   your own. Except for my knowledge that God is present in my stomach,
>   as in every atom of creation, the lime would have killed me. Now that
>   you know the divine meaning of boomerang, never again play tricks on
>   anyone."
>
> The sinner, healed by Trailanga's words, slunk feebly away.
>
> The reversal of pain was not a result of the master's will but of the
>   operation of the law of justice that upholds creation's farthest
>   swinging orb.

Comment: From a book about Trailanga : "one day Trailanga Swami had been in another part of the ashram conversing with a disciple. At one point, the Kali image, having come to life, walked into the room where they were seated and held a conversation with Trailanga Swami, then walked out, returned to the temple and became stone again. The disciple was absolutely stunned and speechless. But Trailangaji simply said to him: “So now what have you got?” meaning that no experience, however amazing, was of any value whatsoever if it did not impart wisdom or meaningful change to the aspirant."

Comment: This is off the wall and also kinda gross : "often Trailanga Swami would stand in the Ganges and make his genitals as large as a fire hose and spray the pilgrims (and police) with the same force as a fire hose. But it was not urine, it was marvelous perfume! He would also go into a Shiva temple and either urinate on the linga or urinate in his hand and then pour it over the linga. Of course, the priests and worshippers went wild, but it would be discovered that it was heavenly perfume, and not urine at all." Bamakhepa also has some peculiar oddball accounts like this with the Tarapith murtis.